# Microsoft Azure - Multi tenant architecture and landing zones

Tags: azure, aws-landing-zone

I am new to Microsoft Azure, so it might be a very naive question.

1. At what level landing zones are created? Like are they created on resource group level, subscription level, tenant level or any other level.
2. Also, in a multi tenant architecture, do different tenants share the same landing zone ?

Answer (score 3):

My experience is that the terminology around tenants and landing zones is not used consistently everywhere. What I have found helpful is to understand the terms and use them like this.

> 1. At what level landing zones are created? Like are they created on resource group level, subscription level, tenant level or any other level.

A landing zone defines the set up of the environment for a development team. A "one size fits all" landing zone approach doesn't work very well, especially when teams have very different demands of their cloud environments. For example, an team doing IaaS lift & shift may be very happy with a resource group that gives them a subnet (feels like on-premise), whereas a team developing serverless applications wants a subscription of their own. So you should prepare your AAD tenant to host multiple landing zones, segregated by Management Group structure.

> 2. Also, in a multi tenant architecture, do different tenants share the same landing zone ?

A **tenant** defines a unit of isolation in a multi-tenant infrastructure. When applied to azure, we should always clarify what kind of a tenant we're talking about. An "AAD Tenant" is a unit of isolation in the global AAD service (all of Microsoft's customers), whereas a "landing zone tenant" is a customer of your landing zone.

From the IaaS lift&shift landing zone example above, your landing zone may be a subscription with a vnet (shared infrastructure). Each of your customers then receives a tenant in that landing zone in the form of a resource group with a subnet. In the serverless landing zone example, the shared infrastructure is the AAD tenant, management group, policies etc.

So in summary, a landing zone always consists of some shared infrastructure that establishes guard rails about how its tenants can use and consume cloud services and a mechanism for provisioning/deprovisioning tenants in that landing zone.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single answer to this.  I most cases I see, the landing zones are done per **Tenant**.  A Tenant is an Identity boundary so typically you select a separate tenant because you want some level of separation (e.g., a production tenant vs a development tenant). An Azure AD tenant is a specific instance of Azure AD containing accounts and groups.

I don't see many multitenant instances sharing a landing zone but I have seen them share services via [**Azure Lighthouse**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/lighthouse/overview).  **Microsoft Sentinel** is a good example of this.  The parent org or main IT Security shop will enable Azure Lighthouse so they can have policies that span multiple tenants and they will stand up a "main" instance of Sentinel which is used to do [cross-tenant hunting queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/lighthouse/how-to/manage-sentinel-workspaces).

Comment: In case multitenant instances share same landing zone, how does different security aspect came into play? For instance, there is a threat(issue) to(with) one of the tenant, how does it impact other tenants?

Comment: Depends on the threat and the mitigations you have in place.  Microsoft uses a Zero Trust approach to ensure compliance and assumes breach.  This means verifying each request regardless of originating tenant.  You can add in Risked-based sign ins to enforce MFA if the platform thinks something is amiss. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/fundamentals/zero-trust

Comment: So is the risk aspect same in both multi account vs multi-tenant architecture?
Also with respect to first answer where you mentioned "landing zones are done per Tenant.", by "Tenant" did you mean "Root Tenant" mentioned in this image https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.rajah.ch%2Ftag%2Fazure%2F&psig=AOvVaw3ailINUFayR4qHQlplZgHl&ust=1651549749661000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=2ahUKEwj03cOy9L_3AhUrQmwGHfeaBKUQjRx6BAgAEAs

Comment: I couldn't read the link you sent but I would encourage you to look at https://intothecloudverse.com/2020/12/07/understanding-tenant-directory-management-group-and-subscriptions-in-azure/